# Deskto icons not showing in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: icons, 22.04

I want to show icons on desktop but icons files showing locked and when I move this to desktop, launching of these icons not happening.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Check permissions!

Comment: Stay out of /usr/share/applications. If you want application icons for frequent access, add them to your dock.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to launch `.desktop` launchers from the desktop in Ubuntu 22.04, the very first time you need to right-click them and select "Allow launching".

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer suggests, you need to right-click on these icons and "allow launching".

**However** it's not advisable to keep such a large number of icons on the desktop, for a number of reasons. You are clogging GNOME that needs to refresh the display with unnecessary work.

Ubuntu desktop is not quite similar as the Windows desktop, in terms of cpu usage, time sharing tasks and many more hidden under the surface in the kernel.

GNOME, KDE etc are built to reside upon a UNIX type kernel that is **Linux**. They are not inherently designed from the root of the operating system, as in Windows or MAC OS.